# React native cannot render the text

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I create a simple math quiz app with React Native the problem is when I run this project on the web it's working fine as I expect however when  I run this project with Expo on an Andriod device I cannot get any score increment but I see in a web browser my score is increased.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {

  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('')
  const [target, setTarget] = useState([])
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0)

  const newQuestion = () => {
    const minimum = 1;
    const maximum = 10;
    const int1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;
    const int2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;
    setTarget([int1, int2])
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    newQuestion()
  }, [score])

 

  const handleAnsewer = () => {
    const total = target[0] + target[1];

    // Check that total against the number
    if (total === Number(inputValue)) {
      setScore( score + 5)
    } else  {
      if(score > 0) {
        setScore( score - 5)
      }
    }

    // Call the function again
    newQuestion();
  }


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 32, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Random Math Quiz</Text>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, }}> {target.join(' + ')} </Text>
      <TextInput
        style={{ height: 40 }}
        placeholder="Answer The Question"
        value={inputValue} onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
      />
      <Button title='Answer' onPress={handleAnsewer} />
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, }}> Your Score: {score}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    paddingTop: 50
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the web, you can't access the changed value using `e.target.value` under `onChange` props.  It returns `undefined` if you do that which explained why your score didn't update.

Instead, you can used `onChangeText` props to access the changed value.

```
// do this instead
onChangeText={(textValue)=> setInputValue(textValue)}

// don't do this   
onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
```